# Duplicate tile in Windows8 start screen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Sometimes I want the same Tile in two groups in the Windows 8 start screen.  Is it doable?

I guess I can make an extra shortcut pointing to the same program and pin it to the start screen.  It seems a bit clumsy to me so I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @KronoS Good question.  My answer isn't as good.  Say I want to have Notepad++ both among text handlers (editors&word processors) and among dev tools.

Comment: @KronoS I want to make desktop tile to be the first tile and also the default location of desktop tile should be on its place coz it is easier to click on bottom left tile, and if it is top left also then we can open desktop with a `Enter Key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look as though there is a way to clone a Tile.

As you pointed out, you create a second shortcut to the same app for application shortcut Tiles.

For Live Tiles, you don't have any options at this point.